# Static Code Analyzer doesn't require to build

Tags: c#, c++, code-analysis, fxcop, static-code-analysis

Maybe this question doesn't make so much sense but I was wondering if there is out there any Static Code Analyzer (C/C++/C#) that warns me about issues on source code files without building the project itself...

I would love to flag the kind of issues that get flagged by Static Code Analyzers like FXCop (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429379(v=vs.80).aspx) without compiling...

Would that be possible somehow?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I would like to do the Static Analysis out of the IDE which means I am looking for something standalone that doesn't need to be plugged into the IDE at all.

Comment: I think that [R#](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=Cj0KEQjw6Ya5BRDdyOewyo_Z_64BEiQA-fVKe2_inJ-6iCbm59MKNAMlNypbXGwI7BEVaXdDnpG3b6gaApvc8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CJOr7t3nscwCFag4cgodvdUIGQ) is something what you want or (at least) it's somewhere near.

Comment: The tools has to parse the file somehow... It can be done in background though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StyleCop** https://stylecop.codeplex.com/

It scans your source code files and not the managed code. Meaning you need not compile it beforehand.

Comment: Is it possible to take StyleCop (Resharper) as a standalone tool and pass files to it?

Comment: Resharper is optional. You can still use StyleCop as separate tool. You don't pass files to it. When you install it will add a plugin in Visual Studio.

Comment: So it won't be possible to use StyleCop as standalone, correct?

Comment: Do you mean you don't have Visual Studio? You have not mentioned it yet. You can run it from inside of Visual Studio or integrate into an MSBuild project. Not just dropping files into it's GUI (it does not have it in fact).